# How do I group js files in a subfolder from webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig

Using Webpack 5, TypeScript 3.9, I have been trying to place all transpiled js files into a `js` subfolder. To no avail. The output files are just placed at the root level of the `dist` folder. Since this is my first time with webpack I might be doing something silly.

My desired output tree:

```
index.html
js/
  main.js
  ....
css/   etc.
```

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development', // doesn't matter if set to 'production' either
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.ts',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            compilerOptions: {
              outDir: './dist/js/' // doesn't seem to do anything;
            }
          }
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,

      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
};
```

**tsconfig** (note the removed outDir)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should let webpack handle where to put the files and not configure that within ts-loader. Try removing the **outDir** configuration from **ts-loader** and change **filename** in **output** to: **filename: 'js/[name].js'**.